# Google Cloud I can't find my Audit Logs, are they deleted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I had my audit logs (firestore) on Google Cloud a month ago. I needed to check something again today and they are gone and I'm not getting any more audit logs even though they are all enabled. What can be the issue?

Comment: Please update your question with specific details of what you did ("a month ago", "today") and what you observed both times. Which flavor of audit logs (admin, data, system)? The documentation is distributed but decent: [storing and routing](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#storing_and_routing_audit_logs); [retention periods](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods). There are several options: your query is incorrect; you've disabled a configurable (e.g. data) audit log; the logs have been archived/filtered...

Comment: Default retention period is 1 month (30 days) for non admin audit logs. So, if you didn't set up a custom log bucket with routing and custom retention period, it's normal, you logs have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing permissons, when I contacted the project owner and he gave me Logging > Logs Admin role then I was able to see the logs again.